# Inappbrowser cordova dont show top bar

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I created an app with Phonegap and it uses Inappbrowser. When I open it, it does not show any top bar to go back.

I open it with the next code:

```
<a onclick=\"window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank', 'location=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done');\">My link</a>
```

I attach an image of the result of my inappbrowser.

[image]

As you can see, I don't have the back button I want.

Any suggestions?

I really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: you have to bind the click event to device ready then call it on the anchor click . Then hope full it will work proper .

Answer (score 0):

To use InAppBrowser you have two choices :

Continue to use `window.open` but you need to overload the one existing :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```

Or use directly `cordova.InAppBrowser.open`

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
```

See latest docs for more details :
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser